# Cannot resolve symbol error in while change text on Text view by button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

Help me I'm trying to develop app for Sudoku Im stuck at this Im just Bsc First yr guy don't know anything

Here My Xml code for my TextView Code

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/change"
        android:text="Not Changed"/>
```

Here is my XML code for Button

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Test Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_sample"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Here is My Java Code

```
public void btn(View view) {
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(change);
        t.setText("Changed");
}
```

If I succeed it will Motivate me and my CLG mates
I'm noob here sorry for bad English
Thanks in Advance

Update :
Answer is Solved
New code for Button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:onClick="btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Test Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_sample"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

New Updated Code for Java

```
public void btn(View view) {
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.change);
        t.setText("Changed");
}
```

Thanks to
[nilesh-rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`findViewById()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int))

Finds a view that was identified by the `android:id` XML attribute that was processed in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Use this

```
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.change);
```

Instead of this

```
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(change);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add click event of you `Button` than please use below edit

Add **`android:onclick="btn"`** in your `Button`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:onclick="btn"
    android:text="Test Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_sample"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: It Works Thanks For Your Suggestion

Comment: @GokulGK happy to help you